# Wrap my head around jQuery Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting my first jQuery plugin.

(YAY... about time!)

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how I can get a publicly accessible function to fire properly.

## Code

```
(function($, doc, win){
    "use strict";
    
    // Our main function
    $.fn.ajaxian = function(options){
        // Our Settings
        var $setts = $.extend({
                CallBack:         null,
                LoadInto:         'body',
                LoadSection:       null,
                LoadingContent: null,
                LoadInEffect:     'fade'
            }, options);
        
        console.log('Plugin Initialized');
        
        var elements = this;
        
        return {
            ManualLoad: function(){
                console.log('Manual Fired');
            },
            elements: function(){
                $(this).on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return $.fn.ajaxian.LoadPage;
                }); 
            }
        };  
        
    };
    
    // Load in a page
    $.fn.ajaxian.LoadPage = function(){
        console.log('Internal Page Load Initialized');  
    };
    
}(jQuery, document, window));
```

## UPDATED CODE

```
(function($, doc, win){
    "use strict";
    
    // Our main function
    $.fn.ajaxian = function(options){
        // Our Settings
        var $setts = $.extend({
                CallBack:         null,
                LoadInto:         'body',
                LoadSection:       null,
                LoadingContent: null,
                LoadInEffect:     'fade'
            }, options);
        
        console.log('Plugin Initialized');
        
        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.fn.ajaxian.LoadPage();
            });
        });
        
    };
    
    // Load in a page
    $.fn.ajaxian.LoadPage = function(){
        console.log('Internal Page Load Initialized');  
    };
    
    // Manual load in a page
    $.fn.ManualLoad = function(){
        console.log('Manual Page Load Initialized');
        $.fn.ajaxian.LoadPage();
    };
    
}(jQuery, document, window));
```

## Usage

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
    // Initialize everything
    Initialize(jQuery);
});

var Initialize = function($){
    var options = {
        CallBack:         function(){console.log('Callback Fired')},
        LoadInto:         '#container',
        LoadSection:       '#content',
        LoaderContent:   null,
        LoadInEffect:     'fade'
    };
    $('a:not(.external), button:not(.external), .internal').ajaxian(options);
    
    $('body').ajaxian(options).ManualLoad();
    
    if(location.pathname == '/'){
        $('body').ajaxian('init', options);
    }
};
```

Now, while I am getting the `Plugin Initialized` in my firebug console, I am getting an error attempting the `ManualLoad`.

It states:
`TypeError: $(...).ajaxian(...) is undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My best guess is that your plugin isn't included soon enough or at all. Can you reproduce in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Maybe a missing return on your main function?

Comment: The error message in Chrome is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ManualLoad' of undefined` which might be more helpful. And indeed, your `.ajaxian` method doesn't return any value. You defined `ManualLoad` to be a property of `ajaxian` itself, not a property of whatever the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajaxian method should return an object that has ManualLoad as a function:

```
$.fn.ajaxian = function() {
    // Our Settings
    var elements = this;
    var $setts = $.extend({}, $.fn.ajaxian.defaults, options);
    console.log('Plugin Initialized');

    elements.on('click', function(e){
        var $clickedElement = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        // do something with clicked element here
    }); 

    return {
         ManualLoad: function(){
             console.log('Manual Fired');
             // use elements here
         }
    }
};
```

Comment: yes, but I am attempting to be able to run this on every link, so I need a `return this.each...` in it?  So I'll need to have internal only functions as well?

Comment: Inside the ajaxian function you can save the this reference and then do anything you want with it.

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: I am attempting to build a `ajaxian` plugin to fire off on certain element clicks.  So I need an internal `LoadPage` function that will fire on each item click... however, I also need to be able to fire-off a `ManualLoad` ... for instance on initial page load, I may want to pop-in a default `other` page

Comment: You can attach a click handler to the `elements`variable (which holds the result of the selector). Inside that click-handler you can retrieve the element that was clicked. For the manual load, you can iterate over all the `element`(this.each ...) and do the same thing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean... let me update the quesion

Comment: I updated the question.  the `click` event never fires

Comment: That's because you never call the function to attach them (elements). Anyway, I updated my answer with what I think you want to do. Now when you call ajaxian on a jQuery element, every time it get's clicked, your method will be called and you can do something with the clicked element.

Comment: Ok.  So what is the advantage of using yours, or what I just updated under UPDATED CODE?  (which is working)

Comment: Now you're creating two plugins: ajaxian and ManualLoad. I thought you wanted ManualLoad to be called on a ajaxian instance. To do that you had to cache the `this`-context in the elements variable.

Comment: ok.  I get what you are saying, but now I'm getting a double firing on the click event.  I can't really show you in a fiddle so: http://beta.pirnie.us

Answer (score 0):

Your ajaxian function is not returning any value!

```
    $.fn.ajaxian = function(options){
        // Our Settings
        var $setts = $.extend({}, $.fn.ajaxian.defaults, options);
        console.log('Plugin Initialized');
        //should return some value.
    };
```